# python flask use 'POST' show Internal Server Error

Tags: python, flask, post

I use `POST` method to do some test, but it can't work

This is my main code：

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def main():
     return render_template('login.html')

@app.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
def result():
     if request.method == 'POST':
         user = request.values['user']
         return render_template('result.html', name=user)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1')
```

and the login.html：

```
<body style="background-color:black">
     <form method="post" action="/login">
         <input type="text" name="user">
         <button type="submit">Submit</button>
     </form>
</body>
```

and result.html：

```
<body style="background-color: black">
     <p style="color: white">Your user name is {{ name }}</p>
</body>
```

When I run, I enter `http://127.0.0.1:5000/`

It can not show the formal page

it shows：
[image]

I don't know how to solve this problem

Comment: Please share the layout of your files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When facing such problems it is a good practice to see the exact error messages from Python interpreter, ie. you can start the webserver in the console and watch its output or enable debug logging.

Your code looks good and I could run it without errors:

- I get a text box with submit button on the landing page;
- I get 'Your user name is ...' as the result

I think your errors might be due to incorrect location of the template files. Make sure you keep your HTML files in the `templates` folder.

Comment: Yap, the error is I do not make the `templates` folder, thanks.

But now I have a new quest, can you help me, I'll add it on the top

Comment: All right, so my answer helped you - you should accept it to conclude this thread and start a new question rather than making edit to this one, because it is a new problem and perhaps other users could contribute to the solution. Please change it.

Answer (score 0):

In order that the templates will be rendered by your flask app properly, you should structure your project in one of the following ways:

1. Your flask app is a module:

```
/application.py
/templates
    /hello.html
```

2. Your flask app is a package:

```
/application
    /__init__.py
    /templates
        /hello.html
```

Answer (score 0):

check your html files location. It should be in 'templates' folder.